# Jade + JQuery Mobile, how to add some sort of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, pug

as in the .jade files that compile into HTML, and I'm also new to JQuery Mobile. I'm initializing JQuery Mobile in this jade file as such..

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js')
```

Is that proper?
Also how would I change something like this...

```
if (elem.onload == 1)                                                   
  input(type = 'checkbox', name = elem.name + '|onl', checked)
else
  input(type = 'checkbox', name = elem.name + '|onl') 
| OnLoad
```

To something that's using a JQuery mobile button.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the question here? Why wouldn´t that be proper? Run your code and try it!

Comment: More or less I'm wondering how to change the checkbox into some sort of JQuery Mobile button. I can't currently test this code.

Answer (score 0):

About the jQuery part, it works properly because I have just test this code, and both contents disappear when clicking on them.

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Holamundo!
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js')
  body
    h1#headTitle Hello, World
    p#content This is an example of Jade.
    script
      $('#headTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
      $('#content').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
```